Using an Azure Managed Identity from within Docker via Visual Studio Code
EDIT: the solution was to add a line RUN sh -c "curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash" in my Dockerfile to install the Azure CLI, and to remove the final line CMD ["python", "app.py"]. You then start the Docker container using docker run -it [image_name] bash, run az login, and follow the instructions. Afterwards you can run python app.py and your app will be able to connect to the database while using a Managed Identity.

Running my web app without Docker (after doing az login from the command line) works like a charm. Running the web app with Docker, but using a username and password instead of a Managed Identity, also works. Now I want to run my web app using Docker while using a Managed Identity.
In Visual Studio Code I have installed the Azure Account extension and successfully signed in to my Azure account. However, when running my Docker image, I get the following error:
Attempted credentials:
    EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
Visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot to troubleshoot this issue.
    ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no response from the IMDS endpoint.
    SharedTokenCacheCredential: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.
    AzureCliCredential: Azure CLI not found on path
    AzurePowerShellCredential: PowerShell is not installed
    AzureDeveloperCliCredential: Azure Developer CLI could not be found. Please visit https://aka.ms/azure-dev for installation instructions and then,once installed, authenticate to your Azure account using 'azd auth login'.
To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot.

The error occurs when I'm trying to run the followin.
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
my_token = credential.get_token('https://database.windows.net/')

It seems like my Azure login is not "fully" passed to either VS Code or the Docker container. What am I missing?

Managed Identity does not work locally. You need to deploy the web app to azure and enable managed identity and assign the role to respective resource.

It does work locally, because I'm able to run the app when not using Docker. It's only when I want to access the database from within my Docker container that I run into problems.

are you using DefaultAzureCredentials method?

Yes, I am. Locally I am able to connect to the database, but only after doing az login first.

DefaultAzureCredential uses multiple method to login. In Locally it uses CLI credentials. which you are logging through az login.   Managed Identity can't be used locally, check here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-integrate-azure-managed-service-identity?tabs=core2x&pivots=framework-dotnet#use-a-managed-identity:~:text=Managed%20identity%20can%27t%20be%20used%20to%20authenticate%20locally%20running%20applications.

No, because it didn't help. I have edited my original post with the solution that I found, where I am now able to start a Docker container but still use password-less login via az login.

This the order which Defaultcredentials follows check here Manage identity is not working but your Azure CLI credentials working for credentials which you are using for az login: https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/#:~:text=library%27s%20credential%20classes.-,DefaultAzureCredential,-DefaultAzureCredential%20is%20appropriate

Ah, so it only seems like Managed Identity is working locally? But in reality it's Azure CLI, and only when the web app is deployed is ManagedIdentityCredential used?

Yet I configured my database to only allow connections from Managed Identity. So isn't az login using my managed identity, but not the ManagedIdentityCredential?

If your credentials have admin access or role in DB it will take Azure CLI credentials

If you exclude Azure CLI fromDefaultAzureCredentials. You will get error for local

As I mentioned in comment Managed Identity does not work locally as mentioned in the MS document.
Also DefaultAzureCredential()  works in this order as mentioned in this Python document.
Environment >> Workload Identity >> Managed Identity >>Azure CLI >> Azure PowerShell >> Azure Developer CLI >> Interactive browser.
That is why, after Azure CLI installation in your docker it worked.
Environment :- To use this  you need to add environment variables and its values.
AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, AZURE_TENANT_ID.
Managed Identity :- To use Managed Identity application should be deployed to Azure and enable System Assigned Managed Identity OR User Assigned Managed Identity in your source service and assign this Identity a role in your Target service.
Azure CLI :- If you have Azure CLI installed and logged in to Azure using az login, it uses those stored credentials.
